# Is it possible to use Firebase auth with cross origin isolation without using Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I've added a feature to my web app that requires using `SharedArrayBuffer`. To access shared `SharedArrayBuffer` my site needs to be cross origin isolated.

I have added the required headers

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

and the feature works.

But now firebase auth isn't working with Google Authentication (Email and password still work). I'm not using Firebase Hosting to host my web app.

I've tried using both the pop up and redirect methods with no luck.

I've tried using my own custom domain `auth.mysite.com` and hosting a copy of my site on firebase hosting but the popup fails as it's a different origin to `mysite.com` with the following messsage

```
To use this resource from a different origin, the server needs to specify a cross-origin resource policy in the response headers:
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-siteChoose this option if the resource and the document are served from the same site.
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-originOnly choose this option if an arbitrary website including this resource does not impose a security risk.
Learn more in the issues tab
```

and redirect just seems to hang waiting for getRedirectResult() to resolve .

Is it possible to get this to work?

Comment: What happens if you try removing the CORP headers only for the login page? You could have a separate page which uses SharedArrayBuffer and has the appropriate CORP headers.

Comment: @grimsteel. I imagine that would work but it’s a single page app.

Comment: @patrick_corrigan Did you find a solution? I'm having this exact issue!

Comment: @trethaller not really. There are solutions for Chrome only using origin trials I think but I need to support Safari. I ended up just doing a full refresh when the user navigates to the page that uses the feature and sending the correct headers for that page.